# DataGridViewComboBoxColumns binding and returning data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridviewcombobox

I am using a `DataGridView` which has some `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns` these columns point to a different dataview. When I set the datasource using a filtered dataview all appears well but sometimes when the combo is changed, the datagrid view is populated with an incorrect value. This only seems to happen when the unfiltered data for the Combo contains multiple rows with the same value that would be assigned to the DisplayMember of the parent Datagridview.

For example (simple example) a datagrid of customers:

```
Name   Country   Shipping town
```

`Country` & `Shipping town` being combos based of foreign keys of dataview of the country and town tables. Obviously the combo of `Shipping towns` is filtered to only show those in the corresponding country. If table of `Shipping towns` contains two entries for Torquay, one in England and one in Australia, when the customer whos country is England is presented with all of the `Shipping Towns` in England, if Torquay is selected the value returned to the parent datagridview is the key value for Torquay in AUSTRALIA even though the filtered dataview for the combo didn't even contain that value. This only happens if the dataview column used as the displaymember for the Combo contains duplicate values.